# Can we freeze selected neurons in a fully connected layer in keras?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

So , I need to freeze only a neuron or two in the fully connected dense layer in keras, so that its weight doesn't change during the course of training. Is there a way to do this in keras ?

Comment: Did you find how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You might want define a mask and set the elements of the mask corresponding to the neuron you want to freeze to 0. This way gradient won't propagate and the neuron won't be trained.

Something similar to:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/contrib/model_pruning

Comment: Went through it. I believe, I have to define the input shape and the scope of the variable to be masked in the apply_mask() method. Any idea how to define the scope to mask pre selected neurons ? this part was not explained clearly